# How do I get a printer's name and port name in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF. I want to add printer name and port (which is currently connected to my system) into a combobox.

Can someone please show me a simple solution?

Comment: Search for PrintDialog sample code. Here is the msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742418.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use the System.Management dll that's part of .net.

```
using System.Management;

ManagementObjectSearcher printers= new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name from Win32_Printer");

foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers.Get())
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", printer.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
```

If you want more information than just the name the following information is available (Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

```
class Win32_Printer : CIM_Printer
{
  uint32   Attributes;
  uint16   Availability;
  string   AvailableJobSheets[];
  uint32   AveragePagesPerMinute;
  uint16   Capabilities[];
  string   CapabilityDescriptions[];
  string   Caption;
  string   CharSetsSupported[];
  string   Comment;
  uint32   ConfigManagerErrorCode;
  boolean  ConfigManagerUserConfig;
  string   CreationClassName;
  uint16   CurrentCapabilities[];
  string   CurrentCharSet;
  uint16   CurrentLanguage;
  string   CurrentMimeType;
  string   CurrentNaturalLanguage;
  string   CurrentPaperType;
  boolean  Default;
  uint16   DefaultCapabilities[];
  uint32   DefaultCopies;
  uint16   DefaultLanguage;
  string   DefaultMimeType;
  uint32   DefaultNumberUp;
  string   DefaultPaperType;
  uint32   DefaultPriority;
  string   Description;
  uint16   DetectedErrorState;
  string   DeviceID;
  boolean  Direct;
  boolean  DoCompleteFirst;
  string   DriverName;
  boolean  EnableBIDI;
  boolean  EnableDevQueryPrint;
  boolean  ErrorCleared;
  string   ErrorDescription;
  string   ErrorInformation[];
  uint16   ExtendedDetectedErrorState;
  uint16   ExtendedPrinterStatus;
  boolean  Hidden;
  uint32   HorizontalResolution;
  datetime InstallDate;
  uint32   JobCountSinceLastReset;
  boolean  KeepPrintedJobs;
  uint16   LanguagesSupported[];
  uint32   LastErrorCode;
  boolean  Local;
  string   Location;
  uint16   MarkingTechnology;
  uint32   MaxCopies;
  uint32   MaxNumberUp;
  uint32   MaxSizeSupported;
  string   MimeTypesSupported[];
  string   Name;
  string   NaturalLanguagesSupported[];
  boolean  Network;
  uint16   PaperSizesSupported[];
  string   PaperTypesAvailable[];
  string   Parameters;
  string   PNPDeviceID;
  string   PortName;
  uint16   PowerManagementCapabilities[];
  boolean  PowerManagementSupported;
  string   PrinterPaperNames[];
  uint32   PrinterState;
  uint16   PrinterStatus;
  string   PrintJobDataType;
  string   PrintProcessor;
  uint32   Priority;
  boolean  Published;
  boolean  Queued;
  boolean  RawOnly;
  string   SeparatorFile;
  string   ServerName;
  boolean  Shared;
  string   ShareName;
  boolean  SpoolEnabled;
  datetime StartTime;
  string   Status;
  uint16   StatusInfo;
  string   SystemCreationClassName;
  string   SystemName;
  datetime TimeOfLastReset;
  datetime UntilTime;
  uint32   VerticalResolution;
  boolean  WorkOffline;
};
```

Edit: 
to assist with understanding this answer I'll go step by step. (create a new WPF application make sure it's called PrinterDisplay, I'll start from blank)

1: Right click on the References item in the SolutionExplorer window, select "Add reference"

2: Select the .NET tab and search for the library System.Mamagement and select it (press ok!)

3: Paste this code in to MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace PrinterDisplay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<SystemPrinter> Printers
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<SystemPrinter>)GetValue(PrintersProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PrintersProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PrintersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Printers", typeof(ObservableCollection<SystemPrinter>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Printers = new ObservableCollection<SystemPrinter>();
            ManagementObjectSearcher printers = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name, PortName from Win32_Printer");
            foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers.Get())
                this.Printers.Add(new SystemPrinter()
                {
                    Name = (string)printer.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                    Port = (string)printer.GetPropertyValue("PortName"),
                });
        }
    }

    public class SystemPrinter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
    }
}
```

4: Paste this code into MainWindow.xam

```
<Window x:Class="PrinterDisplay.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Port}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

5: Press F5 and marvel at the list of printers and ports.

Comment: but showing the exception 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MPS_Printer.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '2'. please help me

Comment: Could you post your constructor code from the MainWindow class.

Comment: i very new to wpf so ,i can't understand what you tell, please post me full code.I have to get the names of all installed printers on my machine.Please help me.

Comment: I've edited the post with a step by step to create a new application that shows a list of printers and ports.